# Click once temporary folder

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am working on a Winforms app that is deployed using *ClickOnce*. In the clickonce deployment, there are two exe's which I will call viewer.exe and editor.exe.

There is an option in the viewer which dumps a bunch of files to a temporary directory and then instructs editor.exe to launch and open all files in this directory.

My problem is that I can't figure out a place within the ClickOnce folder structure that will let me create a temporary folder to dump these files to. Whenever I try to create a subdirectory in `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` I get an error message that:

> [I don't] have permissions to access that directory.

Is there any place within the ClickOnce framework that will let me create a folder to dump files to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have permissions to access that directory.

ClickOnce apps typically have reduced rights due to *Code Access Security* (CAS) which is generally enabled by default.

MSDN:

> Code access security is a mechanism in the .NET Framework that helps limit the access that code has to protected resources and operations. You should configure the code access security permissions for your ClickOnce application to use the zone appropriate for the location of the application installer. [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z17ceyya(v=vs.120).aspx)

Is your app a **full trust** or **partial trust** application?

Try setting your application to **full trust**.

[image]

### Isolated Storage

Alternatively, you may want to consider Isolated Storage (IS) for storing either user or application data.  IS generally works without requiring Full Access CAS.

e.g. to get a unique storage area for the currently executing assembly with respect to the user try:

```
var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()
```

...or if you want a storage area regardless of user try:

```
var storage= IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForAssembly()
```

### More

- [Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx), MSDN

Comment: Very helpful information so I am marking this post as the answer. I found out my problem was that via click once we weren't generating any file name and so it was trying to save a file to a directory, which generates an access exception. It seems I had permissions to write the subfolder all along.

Comment: @spectacularbob lol, don't worry it happens to the best of us. :)  Thanks for the tick good sir.  Cheers

Answer (score -1):

If it really is temporary, then you should be able to use:

[System.IO.Path.GetTempPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx)

and create a subdirectory under there.

Comment: That is the path that I use for non ClickOnce, but it has the same access error when in ClickOnce